# Selecting Item in Array

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to run a query by using a user input. The query is run in a database which has multiple columns (practically a vlookup). The query is run and the output is an array of values.

How do I get the value of only one value (scalar output to put in alert)?

Thanks

I've tried to use methods familiar to java in order to call one field in an array without any success. 
i.e. output_array[0]

```
// define input
// var custno = app.pageFragments.Add_SalesOrder.children.Form1.children.Form1Body.children.CustomerNo_Input;
var custno = 'ENC';
// define location of output
var outputWidget = app.pageFragments.Add_SalesOrder.children.Form1.children.Form1Body.children.CustomerName_Input;
// define datasource
var datasource = app.datasources.SalesOrder;
// query
datasource.query.filters.CustomerNo._startsWith = custno.value;
// load query
datasource.load();
alert(datasource[0]);
```

I expect to get the first entry in the array but instead I get 'Undefined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [datasource documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#DataSource), you'll find out that the datasource is NOT an array, but instead an object. Since you are looking for the first result of the query, then you should access the **items** property of the datasource. That is an array and you can then just access the zero index of the array to get what you need.

```
alert(datasource.items[0]);
```